# I want my view to fit all the screen in React Native

Tags: reactjs, view, native

I am trying to put a background color for an app I am making but it doesn't fit to all the screen and the bottom of it doesn't take the style.

This is my code:

```
  <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        <Image style={{ flex: 1, height: 80, width: 80, alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 23 }}
          source={require('./../src/img/profile.png')} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.fourblock}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.redbox}
          onPress={() => Actions.personal()}>
          <Text style={styles.redboxText}>
            Personal Detail
              </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.redbox}
          onPress={() => Actions.savedschools()}>
          <Text style={styles.redboxText}>
            Saved Schools
             </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.redbox}
          onPress={() => Actions.languages()}>
          <Text style={styles.redboxText}>
            Your Reviews
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

And this is the style I want to put:

```
  main: {
    //marginTop: 52,
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8FF',
    flex: 1,
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<ScrollView>` must be inside `<View style={styles.main}>`

so

```
<View style={styles.main}>
 <ScrollView>
  <View>
   // .........
  </View>
 </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Image style={{ flex: 1, height: 80, width: 80, alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 23 }}
    resizeMode: 'stretch', // or 'cover' . <<------------------
    source={require('./../src/img/profile.png')} />
```

Comment: The problem is that resizeMode doesnt work with view and it gives a warning saying that is an Invalid props style key. Thank you

Comment: https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/tips-for-react-native-images-or-saying-goodbye-to-trial-and-error-b2baaf0a1a4d

Answer (score 1):

One more way you can fit view on all screen is using positioning absolute and make all left, top, right and bottom 0.

Here is an example.

```
<View style={{ position : 'absolute', top : 0, left : 0, right : 0,bottom : 0,}}</View>
```